# Multiple bank accounts for different apps in iTunes connect

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

As we are developing an iPhone app for a customer and he wants to charge for that app, we are wondering if it is possible to have multiple bank accounts in iTunes connect to have the revenues directly on the customers bank account. Whats the best practise for that?

Many thanks in advance
Stefan

Comment: This is not really a programming question.

Comment: Thats right! But directly related to development.

Comment: Your question seems to be about contract and financial issues that have nothing to do with programming or development. This is probably not the best place for this. Have you tried asking Apple directly?

Comment: Will do that, sorry for posting here

Comment: DAMN Stack Overflow SEO.  I have this question too, and this is the first thing that comes up :P

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want to distribute the app yourself on the store, rather than having the customer do it. As someone who does this kind of work himself, I can tell you that this is just silliness. Your customer should be sending you the certificates for you to sign the app, you send him the app for submission, etc. Never put this up under your account, really.

EDIT: You should tell your customer that he needs his own developer account, then guide him through getting you the certificates you need.

Comment: If you were to say 'certificates' to any of my customers they'd have no clue what you are on about. Sometimes it's just much much easier as a developer to deploy your clients apps for them and just have a bank / company assigned to that app. Just sounds like it's half-assed by Apple to be honest.

Comment: @OliverDixon That exposes you to liability that may not be liability you want to accept though. For me, I never wanted that kind of exposure to be even possible, so I always guided through how to make certificates, and whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up another developer account in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean multiple accounts for the customer to be charged at or multiple accounts for your developer to receive their payments at.

If it is the former that sounds impossible to me (your payment is through Apple as a mediator, you should have no knowledge of customer payment methods).

If it is the latter, couldn't you either a) make a different account per app or b) talk to Apple support about this as it is a billing question?

Comment: The app is written for a customer of us. So its his application which he wants to sell over the AppStore. As he has no developer account, the idea was that we publish the software by using our dev account. It would be great to have all the incomes of that app directly transfered to his bank account.