# Is it possible to directly transer income from an app to a certain bank account?

Tags: android, ios, payment

I have just started making apps for iOS and Android. If I make apps for different customers, is it possible to make the income from one app go directly to a customers bank account? It seems like this is something that would come in handy, but I have not been able to find this.

Similar post back in 2010 with no definitive/outdated answer: [Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226990/multiple-bank-accounts-for-different-apps-in-itunes-connect)

Comment: This is off-topic. Please see an accountant and/or lawyer in your country about how that would work as Google/Apple will only want to pay one tax entity per account to make dealing with paying in all of the different countries easy for them.

Comment: @MorrisonChang: Not sure why one would ask an accountant and/or lawyer about Google Play and Apple App Store functionality. Might be off-topic, but it is clearly releated to development.

Comment: Still think that this is related to the business side of things. You are asking about distributing money from one developer/store account on Apple/Google to more than one bank account. Its best to contact them directly if you want this feature. Or just make multiple accounts per client - which means that each client has their own store account. Basically restating the highest ranked answer in your linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of weeks with no answer and more research it seems like this is not possible. Even though, I would like to mention that one can transfer an app from one developer account to another. This means that I can develop and publish an app on my private account then transfer it to a customers account at a later point. This means you can get started on the development right away and worry about the developer accounts and app income later.

Instruction on how to move an app can be found here:

[How to move Android app between developer accounts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en)

[How to move iOS app between developer accounts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)